# Error SASS: Error reading assets\css\main.css.map: no such file or directory

Tags: css, dart, sass, scss-mixins, sass-loader

For those using Windows and encountering an error while compiling SASS files to generate CSS, go to your Windows Defender and disable it. Windows security prevents a third-party file/system (Dart/Sass) from creating new files in the project directory. I hope this helps! Cheers!

I disabled Windows Defender to resolve this issue. After that, I ran the command: "sass --watch sass/main.sass assets/css/main.css."